# Should I perform input validation on the forms or in the class set method?

Tags: c#, validation, class, input

Say I have a database which stores information on customers, and there is an application with various forms to register customers, edit customers, delete customers, etc...

Should input validation (for example, checking the customer's post code is in the correct format) be placed in the Customer class or be done on the form?  Currently I have it in the class and I am throwing a custom exception if the value is not of the correct format.

Comment: What you are doing is the correct way (better way). What if you decide to use your customer class in a web application or console application: If you do the validation in the form, you will need to rewrite the validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases of validations:

1. Required
2. Almost Required

### Required

The validations which you are doing in the class/backend are the validation which you cannot ignore. If you do,this can leave your data in `heywired` state. So must do this!

### Almost Required

The validation in the UI is not essential, but almost always a part of a quality app. We build an app for users, therefore UX(user experience) is of paramount importance. Validation in the UI gives the user immediate feedback and keep the correction cycle short. This is of more importance as the form grows.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which framework you are using but it would make sense to put form validation in the class which Handels your tables. Thats the framework im  currently using https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html. It would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the architecture of you app.
If you want your app to be extensible and modular, I recomnd you to recpect for  MVC Pattern (Model,View,Controller).
In this case the Model is: Customer Class (That stores only the data of the customer 
The View is : The Form
And you should put the control of the data : checking the inputs, storing data in db etc.. (the business logic) in a class Named for exemple CustomerController. 
[MVC Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: I have something like this.  I have the forms, classes and database access layers (where I store all the SQL functions i.e. UpdateCustomer).  Its not exactly the same though, as I'm checking input in the Customer class, but performing SQL from the access layer.  Should I change this?

Comment: I think you should just move checking input and all the staff ( in a separated class and let the Customer class contains just Customer data. this ll be better than putting all the staff in the Customer class.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should do this in both places. Things like required field are good examples of UI validation and frameworks support this out of the box.

But that doesn't mean your business layer shouldn't still check if the required values are present, specially if you have api's that can be called without the UI layer. Also the business layer must validate more complex cases like existing username, etc.